# Need to conduct validation using PROC SQL for values appearing in a data table against a master table

Tags: mysql, sas

I have 2  tables  called collateral and collateral type master in an SQL server database which I'm accessing through SAS Enterprise guide

Both have two columns COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE & COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE , the *combination* of which i need to validate against entries in the master, and only for reporting date 31st December 2021 records

Eg -  (COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE, COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE) = (70,70) , (70,701) , etc

The issue is that the data type for the fields should be numeric as per the data template  but as per the structure (definition ? ) of the table in the database , only COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE is numeric, as it should be, in the collateral table but the rest are character.

I need help with a query that can help me check out / validate the values appearing in the data table against the master

The code that i have tried till now

```
LIBNAME prcr SQLSVR Datasrc=PRCR SCHEMA=dbo AUTHDOMAIN="SQLAuth01" ;
/*COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE*/
/*COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE*/proc sql;
/*create table temp_1 as*/
select count(1)as cnt, COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE
from prcr.TB_IFRS9_COLLATERAL_TYPE_MAS
group by COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE
order by COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE;
quit;proc sql;
create table temp_1 as
select distinct (COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE,COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE)
from prcr.TB_IFRS9_COLLATERAL
where REPORTING_DATE in ("31DEC2021"d) ;
quit;data temp_2;
set temp_1;
COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE_1 = put(COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE, best32.);
run;proc sql;
create table coll_sub_type_code_in as
select * from prcr.TB_IFRS9_COLLATERAL_TYPE_MAS
where COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE in (select COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE from temp_1);
quit;
/*IN ---- NOTE: Table WORK.TEST_1 created, with 224 rows and 5 columns.*/proc sql;
create table coll_sub_type_code_notin as
select * from prcr.TB_IFRS9_COLLATERAL_TYPE_MAS
where COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE not in (select COLLATERAL_SUB_TYPE_CODE from temp_1);
quit;
/*NOT IN---NOTE: Table WORK.TEST_1 created, with 661 rows and 5 columns. */
/*Step:-2*/proc sql;
create table coll_type_code_in as
select * from prcr.TB_IFRS9_COLLATERAL_TYPE_MAS
where COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE in (select COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE_1 from temp_2);
quit;/*NOTE: Table WORK.COLL_TYPE_CODE_IN created, with 0 rows and 5 columns.*/proc sql;
create table coll_type_code_notin as
select * from prcr.TB_IFRS9_COLLATERAL_TYPE_MAS
where COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE in (select COLLATERAL_TYPE_CODE_1 from temp_2);
quit;
```

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SQL `EXCEPT` operator to find the keys of detail records that do not match a master table.

Example:

Valid master keys are only code=3|6 and subcode=2|4 and detail has a full *coverage*, and thus some detail records have bad keys.

```
data master;
  do code = 3, 6;
    do subcode = 2, 4;
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data detail(keep=code subcode);
  do code = 1 to 7;
    length subcode $10;
    do x = 1 to 5;
      subcode = put(x,10.);
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc sql; 
  create table bad_detail as
  select code, detail.subcode from
  (select code, input(subcode,best32.) as subcode, subcode as s from detail) as detail
  except
  select code, subcode from master
  ;
```

The red lines show where master keys (i.e. the good ones) were removed from the list of detail keys (i.e. unchecked records that can have a bad key)

[image]